# Can custom Excel Ribbon tab buttons be clicked while editing a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an XLAM add-in with an associated custom Ribbon tab working well in Excel, apart from one strange behaviour: when a user is editing a cell (i.e. the cursor is within an Excel cell, or the formula bar, and editing the formula), the buttons on my custom Ribbon tab do nothing.
Specifically, the intent of one of the buttons is to lookup valid arguments for a custom function (these are validated against a cached list that changes, so not a hard-coded validation), and ideally I would like the user to be able to start typing the formula, then click the Ribbon button to insert their desired argument text, and continue in the formula bar.

Is this a Ribbon configuration thing, or is it a not-possible-with-custom-ribbons thing? I notice that I can highlight part of an Excel formula string and use Home > Copy, so it does not appear to be the *entire* Ribbon that fails to register click events while in cell-edit mode...

Comment: You can't run VBA while in edit mode, so...

Comment: @Rory, is that an authoritative answer? You came across a little inconclusive, so just checking you're sure that it's systematically not possible?